# update-alternatives: change version of LLVM tools

Tags: 14.04, update-alternatives

I have llvm 3.4 and 3.5 installed on my system. I want to switch between these version. This is possible using update-alternatives, however it changes default version of only one tool of the package and it is neccessary to call this command multiple times - for each tool of the package.

Isn't there a tool that could change default version of all tools in package (besides writing a shell script, which calles update-alternatives multiple times)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible - there are dependencies (argument --slave) in update-alternatives which makes exactly what I need!